# The meaning of "Baby's First Broker"

Tags: idioms, terminology

I was in the middle of a subtitle translation for a video, when I encountered a phrase I have not heard before. I assumed it might be an idiom, but failed to find any clues to it's meaning anywhere on the web, including this and English Language Learners StackExchange. I tried seraching for jargon-related queries but neither this helped me find the answer. I am relucant on moving on or describing any of it in my own words, as I believe it to play an important role in the meaning of the whole scene. Sadly, I'm not even sure of the original meaning to be able to at least circumlocute the script in case I couldn't directly translate it.

Now I would like to get to the bottom of this not just for the sake of the translation, but also because I'm personally curious about the meaning of the phrase.

The setting of the video is a parody of The Wolf of Wall Street (2013) movie starring "meme brokers" - people who buy and sell memes on the meme stock exchange. At one point, the stocks started tanking and they had to seek an advice from a person who was later referred to as a "baby's first broker", as seen in the following sentence:

> "Now I've got maniacs spending my points however they please and now baby's first broker's trying to help me out."

I believe the meaning might be somehow closely tied to the original movie (a reference, perhaps?) but sadly I haven't seen that either.

I'm not a native English speaker and I couldn't come up with a supposed meaning. Also it might be worth noting I'm just an enthusiast adding subtitles in my native language to English YouTube videos made by independednt fimmakers in my free time.

Thank you for reading and any and all effort in answering!

Comment: Not familiar with that flick, or the specific term "baby's first broker", but "baby's first X" is a fairly popular sales tag for items of all sorts intended to be "instructive" to infants.  You will find such items as "baby's first truck" and "baby's first Bible".  Used in a satirical sense for terms such as "baby's first brothel".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not familiar with that flick and it seems 96% obvious that "baby's first broker" is a derogatory reference to a broker so poorly qualified, lacking in experience or just plain incapable that he could only be expected to find work from children so young that getting them to sign a contract would be … uh… like stealing candy from a baby… that is, in the adult world he would be seen as a "Mickey Mouse broker"; one who is in practical terms, wholly useless.